# How to Prevent Battery Full Notifications in Mi 2 Band?

Tags: xiaomi, silent-mode, sleep, mi-band-2

Situation: to prevent Mi 2 Band's battery full vibration, which wakes me up; the notification bypasses Android's own Silent Mode
Secondary solution: use *[Do Not Disturb](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cabooze.buzzoff)* applicaiton of Playstore

Band is in the connection with the phone by [Mi Fit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xiaomi.hm.health&hl=lt) of Playstore. 
My Pebble is connected to my phone by *Gadgetbridge*. 
Situation

- In Mi Fit, DND active from 2100-0700
- Android's Silent mode active but not effective
- In Mi Fit, I find no setting about disabling the vibration of the band about the battery full status

My Settings > Notifications > App specific for Mi Fit

[image]

Phone: Samsung Galaxy S4, Oneplus 3
Phone OS: Cyanogenmod 13
Activity band: Xiaomi MI Band 2
Smart watch: Pebble Classic 1
Pebble firmware: 3.12.2 (newest 9.8.2016)
Pebble hardware: V3R3
Ticket at Gadgetbridge github about the issue: [Can you Stop Vibrations of Mi 2 Band about Battery Full Status with Gadgetbridge?](https://github.com/Freeyourgadget/Gadgetbridge/issues/384)

Comment: So you're trying to stop Mi 2 app notifications from showing up on your Pebble, or what?

Comment: So you want your CyanogenMod phone to not vibrate when Mi Fit has a notification about full battery?

Comment: What about blocking all notifications from the Mi Fit app—to do that (though I'm sure you know how), just hold down on a notification from the Mi Fit app, hit the settings icon, and tap `Block All`.

Comment: Go to the Settings app on your phone, go to Apps, then find Mi Fit in the list. There, you'll see a `Notifications` row, click on that. Then tap the toggle for `Block` or `Block All` to on. That will block all Mi Fit notifications.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. I believe that as long as "Treat As Priority" is unchecked for Mi Fit in App Notification Settings, that Mi Fit cannot make notification noises. Go to the Settings app on your phone, go to `Sound and Notification`, go to `App Notifications`, and find Mi Fit in the list. In the Mi Fit notifications settings, uncheck `Treat as priority`. That will block sounds from Mi Fit notifications when your phone is on Priority DND (or Alarms Only, or Total Silence).

Comment: Huh, that's very mysterious. Is there a way you can customize notification sounds in the Mi fit app itself? And can you try going into Priority DND mode? And customizing Priority DND mode in settings to turn off all sounds other than alarms and calls (settings -> Sound and notification -> Do not disturb) might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by getting the second phone for my Mi Band 2 because I use Pebble at work, thus causing me much complications because no two internet gadget -support is not supported at the same time. This way, you can control the notifications of battery full -status stably.